# Android WebView with SwipeRefreshLayout not working properly with inner scroll on webpage

Tags: android, mobile, webview, odoo, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to develop Hybrid Application with Android WebView that loads website on mobile webview.

Adding WebView Object runtime in FrameLayout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/webViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

For `SwipeRefreshLayout` enable/disable when page is on top, added `TreeObserver` for scroll detection of `WebView`

```
odooWebView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(odooWebView.getScrollY() == 0);
        }
    });
```

It working fine with all pages having scrollable contents. But pages with inner vertical scroll stucked with swipe refresh

Video comparison with app and chrome browser:

App:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7bMj_vvgmpveEV2MkNYc0xOY3c/view?usp=sharing 
Chrome App: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7bMj_vvgmpvUktYQVpONXl1ekk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you find any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Comment: any fix on this yet?